# Embed non-PDF files (e.g., BibTex) into PDF with hyperlink in the PDF

Tags: external-files, embedding, attachfile, embedfile

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`intopdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/intopdf)

### Aim

I want to achieve following:

1. Embed `paper.bib` into PDF
2. `paper.bib` should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype `application/x-bibtex`
3. Have `paper.bib` listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader

   [image: attachment view]
4. The attachment section should have a proper description
5. Have `paper.bib` listed in the "\EmbedFiles" in PDF (can be checked with Acrobat Pro)

   [image: EmbedFiles]
6. Have `paper.bib` listed in the bookmarks section

   [image: bookmarks section in SumatraPDF]
7. Have a working link to `paper.bib` in the PDF

   [image: working link]

   [image: single click]
8. Have the link visible also in the printed version
9. No strange additional icon. Following should not appear:

   [image: strange icon]
10. Link should be marked as link

    [image: marked link]

### Related questions:

- [How do I make an attached file display like a link?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17926/9075)
- [How do I make an attached non-pdf file display like a link?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230581/9075)
- [Opening a non-PDF file clicking on a bookmark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260430/9075)

### Tried solutions

#### 1. [embedfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) together with [hypgotoe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypgotoe)

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hypgotoe}

\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@article{demo,
  author={Demo Author}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\embedfile[
  desc={BibTeX entry of this paper},
  mimetype=application/x-bibtex
]{paper.bib}

\href{gotoe:embedded=paper.bib}{BibTeX}

\end{document}
```

1. YES: Embed `paper.bib` into PDF
2. YES: `paper.bib` should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype `application/x-bibtex`
3. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader
4. YES: The attachment section should have a proper description
5. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the "\EmbedFiles" in PDF
6. Partially: Have `paper.bib` listed in the bookmarks section (OK: SumatraPDF, NOT OK: Acrobat Pro X)
7. NO: Have a working link to `paper.bib` in the PDF. SumatraPDF opens the `tex` file, Acrobat Reader does nothing
8. YES: Have the link visible also in the printed version
9. YES: No strange additional icon
10. YES: Link should be marked as link

#### 2. [navigator](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator)

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{navigator}

\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@article{demo,
  author={Demo Author}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\embeddedfile[BibTeX entry of this paper]{paper.bib}{paper.bib}

\openfilelink{paper.bib}{BibTeX}

\end{document}
```

1. YES: Embed `paper.bib` into PDF
2. YES: `paper.bib` should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype `application/x-bibtex`
3. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader
4. YES: The attachment section should have a proper description
5. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the "\EmbedFiles" in PDF
6. NO: Have `paper.bib` listed in the bookmarks section
7. PARTIALLY: Have a working link to `paper.bib` in the PDF: Double click opens file in SumatraPDF, not working in Acrobat Reader
8. YES: Have the link visible also in the printed version
9. YES: No strange additional icon
10. NO: Link should be marked as link

#### 3. [attachfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile)

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@article{demo,
  author={Demo Author}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

% We need "doubleprint", because the text of \textattachfile is not printed when printing a PDF
% We use the idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19045/9075, accepting that
% the pointers to the files are renderedin semi-bold way
\newlength{\Urlname}
\newcommand{\doubleprint}[1]{\setlength{\Urlname}{\widthof{#1}}\hspace{-\Urlname}#1}

\textattachfile[%
  print=true,%
  color=0 0 0,%
  icon=Paperclip,%
  description={BibTeX entry of this paper},%
  mimetype=application/x-bibtex%
]{paper.bib}{BibTeX}%
\doubleprint{BibTeX}

\end{document}
```

1. YES: Embed `paper.bib` into PDF
2. YES: `paper.bib` should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype `application/x-bibtex`
3. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader
4. YES: The attachment section should have a proper description
5. NO: Have `paper.bib` listed in the "\EmbedFiles" in PDF
   [image: not embedded]
6. NO: Have `paper.bib` listed in the bookmarks section
7. Partially: Have a working link to `paper.bib` in the PDF. Double Click in Acrobat Reader, single click in SumatraPDF
8. YES: Have the link visible also in the printed version
9. NO: Strange additional icon Acrobat Reader
10. NO: Link should be marked as link

Debug Information

The `/Type /Embeddedfile` entry is appearing next to the embedding text in the PDF, not in the global file catalog:

[image: Embedded File Information]

The icon is because of the attachment. In Acrobat Pro, one can drag'n'drop the attachment:

[image: Draggable Attachment]

#### 4. [embedfile](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) together with stackoverflow tweaks

This solution extends the first solution with

- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230581
- [Opening a non-PDF file clicking on a bookmark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260430)

Proposal:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[atend]{bookmark}

% How do I make an attached non-pdf file display like a link?
% (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230581)
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\embeddedfilelink}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \pdfstartlink
      attr{%
        \Hy@setpdfborder
        \ifx\@pdfhighlight\@empty
        \else
          /H\@pdfhighlight
        \fi
        \ifx\@filebordercolor\relax
        \else
          /C[\@filebordercolor]%
        \fi
      }%
      user{%
       /Subtype/Link%
       /A<<%
         /Type/Action%
         /S/JavaScript%
         /JS(this.exportDataObject({cName: "#1", nLaunch: 2}))%
       >>%
      }%
      \relax
    \Hy@colorlink\@filebordercolor#2%
    \close@pdflink
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@article{demo,
  author={Demo Author}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\embedfile[
  desc={BibTeX entry of this paper},
  mimetype=application/x-bibtex
]{paper.bib}

\embeddedfilelink{paper.bib}{BibTeX}
%hint from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260439/9075
\BookmarkAtEnd{
  \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
  \bookmark[level=0,rawaction={
    /S/JavaScript/JS(%
      this.exportDataObject({cName: "paper.bib", nLaunch: 2})%
    )%
  }]{paper.bib}
}

\end{document}
```

1. YES: Embed `paper.bib` into PDF
2. YES: `paper.bib` should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype `application/x-bibtex`
3. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader
4. YES: The attachment section should have a proper description
5. YES: Have `paper.bib` listed in the "\EmbedFiles" in PDF
6. Partially: Have `paper.bib` listed in the bookmarks section (Twice in SumatraPDF, OK: Acrobat Pro X)
7. Partially: Have a working link to `paper.bib` in the PDF. SumatraPDF opens the `tex` file, Acrobat Reader opens the correct application
8. YES: Have the link visible also in the printed version
9. YES: No strange additional icon
10. YES: Link should be marked as link

### Debugging hints

The tools to list the internal PDF structure are discussed at [Best tool for inspecting PDF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3549541/873282). The screenshots above are made by Acrobat Professional X. [iText RUPS](https://github.com/itext/rups/) seems to be close to Acrobat Professional's capabilities.

### Question

How to achieve that eat least following goals are met:

1. `paper.bib` should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype `application/x-bibtex`
2. Have `paper.bib` listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader
3. The attachment section should have a proper description
4. Have `paper.bib` listed in the bookmarks section
5. Have a working link to `paper.bib` in the PDF
6. Have the link visible also in the printed version

Optionally, following would be good:

7. No strange additional icon.
8. Link should be marked as link

Comment: +1 for the research effort. Links to embedded *PDF* files are supported by AR at least. If you resort to JavaScript, you will loose most of the PDF viewers.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Doesn't this conflate different things? I thought that bookmarks pointed to things in this file; links pointed to things either in this file or somewhere else; embedded and attached files are distinct kinds of things, neither of which are in this file. So how can it make sense to have an embedded or attached file in the bookmarks? I could understand having a link and, say, including the point at which that link appears in the bookmarks. But the book mark will point to that bit of this document and not the embedded or attached file. Can the desiderata be understood as consistent?

Comment: @cfr A PDF bookmark can have different kind of actions. It is not restricted to links.

Comment: For me, `attachfile` looks the most promising. If only SumatraPDF shows the Bookmark and Acrobat Reader in the "Attached Files" tab, it is OK for me. Maybe, there is no solution, because `attachfile` attaches the file using an annotation (`/T:Annot /S:FileAttachment`; therefore also the icon) and this annotation enables the viewers to correctly treat the file.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I didn't know that. I always thought they were bookmarks, albeit of an electronic variety. I guess I thought you needed other elements for other functions.

Comment: @koppor Note that some of what you are seeing is likely to be viewer-dependent. How viewers present embedded files is, I think, an example of this and the same might be true for attached files - I'm not sure. (Or have I got that the wrong way around? I always forget which is which.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution does not solve all the problems, but it didn't fit into a comment:

This is similar to `attachfile`, but without `\doubleprint` and 9, 10 fixed and making the annotation unmovable:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{paper.bib}
@article{demo,
  author={Demo Author}
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\attachandlink[4]{%
  \leavevmode%
  \immediate\pdfobj stream attr {
    /Subtype /\pdfescapename{#2}
  } file{#1}%
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<
    /Type /Filespec
    /F (\pdfescapestring{#1})
    /EF << /F \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R >>
  >>}%
  \pdfstartlink user {
    /Subtype /FileAttachment
    /FS \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /F 416
    /CA 0
    /Contents (\pdfescapestring{#3 Double click to open.})
  }%
  \pdfstartlink attr{
    \Hy@setpdfborder
    \ifx\@pdfhighlight\@empty%
    \else%
      /H\@pdfhighlight
    \fi%
    \ifx\@urlbordercolor\relax%
    \else%
      /C[\@urlbordercolor]
    \fi%
  } user {
    /Subtype /Link
  }%
  #4%
  \pdfendlink%
  \pdfendlink%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\attachandlink{paper.bib}{application/x-bibtex}{BibTeX entry for this paper}{BibTeX}

\end{document}
```

1. YES: Embed paper.bib into PDF
2. YES: paper.bib should be opened with the OS tool associated with mimetype application/x-bibtex
3. YES: Have paper.bib listed in the attachment section in Acrobat Reader
4. YES: The attachment section should have a proper description
5. NO: Have paper.bib listed in the "/EmbeddedFiles" in PDF ￼
6. NO: Have paper.bib listed in the bookmarks section
7. YES: Have a working link to paper.bib in the PDF, double click is required on Adobe Reader
8. YES: Have the link visible also in the printed version
9. YES/NO: Strange additional icon in Adobe Reader only on Mouseover
10. YES: Link should be marked as link

The Goal 5, listed in `/EmbeddedFiles`, would be easy to add and probably would add `paper.bib` to the bookmarks section in SumatraPDF as well (I'm not sure about this one, I couldn't get SumatraPDF to show a bookmarks section for any PDF), but there would be side effects:
To open the embedded file without Javascript in Adobe Reader, it has to be added as a `File Attachment Annotation` at a special location, while files referenced in the `/EmbeddedFiles` directory are attached to the whole document.
One file can be referenced in both ways, but then Acrobat Reader for example will list the file twice.

Comment: Thank you! i) Goal 5: I saw the bookmarks at some of the minimal examples above. Seems, it just crawls the `/EmbeddedFiles` section. I also encountered the double listing when using `\embedfile` in addition to `textattachfile`. So, no boomarks. ii) my Acrobat Reader DC does not show any desription, but his should be fixable easily. iii) SumatraPDF opens the file with a single click. Great. iv) Acrobat Reader does not show the link cursor, but the text cursor. I also need to double click, which is not the common thing for that colored links. Can there be done something about it?

Comment: I fixed ii), but this caused the icon to reappear. Sadly the attached files `/Desc` is ignored by Adobe Reader for File Annotations and the only alternative is adding Content to the annotation causing the icon. I added some flags to hide the icon except on mouseover or when the annotation is clicked.

Comment: Thank you four patience. a) I got a description now in Acrobat Reader DC and PDF-XChange Viewer. Very nice. b) With double click, the file is opened. With the fourth solution (emabedfile-tweaked), I I just need a single link in Acrobat Reader. In case this is hard to achieve, maybe the tooltip should be extended with "Double click to open". In SumatraPDF everything works fine. No action in PDF-XChange viewer, but this is OK for me, since I do not use that tool.

Comment: @kopporOpening the file with a single click is only possible with Javascript, which does not work with SumatraPDF. I tried combining this with the `navigator` approach to add SumatraPDF support, but on my system SumatraPDF could not even open the link in the navigator example. The Tooltip can't controled independent from the file description because Adobe ignores most other fields for file attachments, so we would have to add "Double click to open" to the description.

Comment: These XXX tools. I retried to examples: In the case of `attachfile`, it worked in SumatraPDF with a single click, but not with Acrobat Reader. A double click was necessary. OK, +1 for "Double click to open." Unsure about the preceeding dot. `. Double click to open.` might not work in all cases. -- I needed to add it only at the second #3 to have it appearing everywhere. What is the the first `\Desc` string for?

Comment: The `/Desc` is the file description, but it is only used for files in the `/EmbeddedFiles` tree. So it is ignored here and I only set it because this is how I wanted it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74149/discussion-between-koppor-and-marcel-kruger).

Comment: +1: You have amazing packages on CTAN.